# add/show X more comments needs to be seperated

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web

When wanting to, simply, see "more comments" on SE sites the cursor is automatically put into the comment box.

On a computer this really isn't a problem - in fact I probably wouldn't even notice. But on the mobile website it's a real pain in the next because every time it not only selects the comment box but zooms right in on the comments box (at least on iOS) - in order to read the other listed comments you first need to zoom out just to be able to even fully see what is written.

I would propose removing the automatic selecting of the "add comments" box - because it can be selected very simply anyway.